# Disable Command Prompt When Running LibVLC with QT on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, vlc, libvlc

I have a c++ program that uses libVLC and QT.  When the program starts it creates the QT UI but it also opens a command prompt that holds any VLC errors.  Does anyone know a way to suppress to CMD window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use "--extraintf=logger" as command to libvlc.